# Webpack 5 doesn't update the bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to create a boilerplate with Webpack 5 and React to understand the details all of the elements. And it seems like everything works properly except the updating bundle.js in memory.

When I run the 'webpack serve' command the server starts, then I modify script, page is reloaded but there are no changes.

I have next statement in config files
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.64.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const DotenvWebpackPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        liveReload: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /nodeModules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }),
        new DotenvWebpackPlugin({
            path: '.env'
        })
    ],
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true,
    },
}
```

Logs:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.0.106:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'D:\Projects\boilerplates\react-app\src' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of D:\Projects\boilerplates\react-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
asset index.bundle.js 4.06 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 287 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.1 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.06 MiB 45 modules
modules by path ./src/ 3.29 KiB
  modules by path ./src/*.js 477 bytes
    ./src/index.js 200 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.js 277 bytes [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/*.css 2.83 KiB
    ./src/app.css 2.24 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/app.css 601 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.64.1 compiled successfully in 3107 ms
assets by path *.js 4.06 MiB
  asset index.bundle.js 4.06 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
  asset main.c161a0c51f50fe5a9631.hot-update.js 676 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main)
asset index.html 287 bytes [emitted]
asset main.c161a0c51f50fe5a9631.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint main 4.06 MiB = index.bundle.js 4.06 MiB main.c161a0c51f50fe5a9631.hot-update.js 676 bytes
cached modules 1.07 MiB [cached] 48 modules
runtime modules 27.1 KiB 13 modules
./src/App.js 277 bytes [built]
webpack 5.64.1 compiled successfully in 118 ms
assets by status 4.06 MiB [cached] 1 asset
asset index.html 287 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.07 MiB (javascript) 27.1 KiB (runtime) [cached] 62 modules
webpack 5.64.1 compiled successfully in 15 ms
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
assets by status 4.06 MiB [cached] 1 asset
asset index.html 287 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.07 MiB (javascript) 27.1 KiB (runtime) [cached] 62 modules
webpack 5.64.1 compiled successfully in 16 ms
```

You can check the boilerplate here in [repo](https://github.com/ScientismResidence/boilerplates)

So, page is reloaded successfully but there are no changes. What the problem can be there?

**UPDATE 1**:

I'm updating jsx inside of this script for anything else - src/app.js

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
    return (<div>
        <h2>Welcome to React App</h2>
        <h3>Date : {new Date().toDateString()}</h3>
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

But the changes are visible only after restarting webpack dev server.

To reproduce the problem you can easily clone the repo and run this script in react-app directory:

```
npm i
npm start
```

Comment: What script did you change and what did you change it from and to what

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I've added this clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
index.js had:

```
import App from "./App"
```

but correct one is:

```
import App from "./app"
```

Strange thing. It's like there should be an error instead of silence.